# SignalR OnConnected and On Dissconnected overriden methods are not fired when proxy hub connection is established

Tags: c#, signalr

Connection establishes successfully with connection ID but proxy method is not fired, I am trying to track number of active users.

```
public class CounterHub : Hub// Proxy Hub
        {
            static long counter = 0;
            public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
            {

                counter = counter + 1;
                Clients.All.UpdateCount(counter);// Client Proxy Method
                return base.OnConnected();
            }

            public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
            {
                counter = counter - 1;
                Clients.All.UpdateCount(counter);//Client proxy method
                return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
            }
        }
```

Javasrcitp to establish Connection and call proxy client method

```
 $

(function () {
                        var counterHub = $.connection.counterHub;
                        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                            console.log("Connection Established" + $.connection.hub.id);

                        }).fail(function () {
                            console.log('Could not Connect!'); 
                        });


                        $.extend(counterHub.client, {
                            UpdateCount: function (count) {
                                console.log(count);
                            }
                        })


                        counterHub.client.UpdateCount = function (count) {
                            $("#counter").text(count);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: maybe try using `signalR JSClient` instead https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client

Comment: @Aarif tried your suggestion same problem onconnected is not firing

Comment: verified connection being built on sockets in network tools in browser?

Comment: Yes connection is establishing successfully and i could log connection ID as well

Answer (score 0):

Client method needs to be declared before your connection.

```
$(function () {
    var counterHub = $.connection.counterHub;

    counterHub.client.UpdateCount = function (count) {
         $("#counter").text(count);
    }

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
           console.log("Connection Established" + $.connection.hub.id);
    }).fail(function () {
           console.log('Could not Connect!'); 
    });

    $.extend(counterHub.client, {
        UpdateCount: function (count) {
        console.log(count);
        }
    })


  });
```

Not sure what you are trying to do with the $.extend there, as I have never used it that way. That may need to be moved as well.